# Type a variable to be any of the keys in a map?

Tags: typescript

I have a map and a function. I want the function to accept as parameter any of the keys in the map. My code below doesn't work. `keyof typeof svgAttributeToCssStyle` is `"clear" | "delete" | "forEach" | "get" | ...` rather than `["alignment-baseline", "baseline-shift", ...]` as I would like it to be.

Map:

```
const svgAttributeToCssStyle = new Map<string, keyof CSSStyleDeclaration>([
  ["alignment-baseline", "alignmentBaseline"],
  ["baseline-shift", "baselineShift"],
  ["clip", "clip"],
  ["clip-path", "clipPath"],
  ["color", "color"],
  ["color-interpolation", "colorInterpolation"],
  ["color-interpolation-filters", "colorInterpolationFilters"],
  ["cursor", "cursor"],
  ["direction", "direction"],
  ["display", "display"],
  ["dominant-baseline", "dominantBaseline"],
  ["enable-background", "enableBackground"],
  ["fill", "fill"],
  ["fill-opacity", "fillOpacity"],
  ["fill-rule", "fillRule"],
  ["filter", "filter"],
  ["flood-color", "floodColor"],
  ["flood-opacity", "floodOpacity"],
  ["font-family", "fontFamily"],
  ["font-size", "fontSize"],
  ["font-size-adjust", "fontSizeAdjust"],
  ["font-stretch", "fontStretch"],
  ["font-style", "fontStyle"],
  ["font-variant", "fontVariant"],
  ["font-weight", "fontWeight"],
  ["glyph-orientation-horizontal", "glyphOrientationHorizontal"],
  ["glyph-orientation-vertical", "glyphOrientationVertical"],
  ["image-rendering", "imageRendering"],
  ["kerning", "kerning"],
  ["letter-spacing", "letterSpacing"],
  ["lighting-color", "lightingColor"],
  ["marker-end", "markerEnd"],
  ["marker-mid", "markerMid"],
  ["marker-start", "markerStart"],
  ["mask", "mask"],
  ["opacity", "opacity"],
  ["overflow", "overflow"],
  ["pointer-events", "pointerEvents"],
  ["shape-rendering", "shapeRendering"],
  ["stop-color", "stopColor"],
  ["stop-opacity", "stopOpacity"],
  ["stroke", "stroke"],
  ["stroke-dasharray", "strokeDasharray"],
  ["stroke-dashoffset", "strokeDashoffset"],
  ["stroke-linecap", "strokeLinecap"],
  ["stroke-linejoin", "strokeLinejoin"],
  ["stroke-miterlimit", "strokeMiterlimit"],
  ["stroke-opacity", "strokeOpacity"],
  ["stroke-width", "strokeWidth"],
  ["text-anchor", "textAnchor"],
  ["text-rendering", "textRendering"],
  ["transform", "transform"],
  ["unicode-bidi", "unicodeBidi"],
  ["visibility", "visibility"],
  ["word-spacing", "wordSpacing"],
  ["writing-mode", "writingMode"],
]);
```

function:

```
export function getPresentationAttribute(attribute: keyof typeof svgAttributeToCssStyle) {
  ...
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the type of the map key explicitly as `string` TS will not preserve the type of the key.

If you let TS infer the type of the key, and you also use an `as const` assertion on the map source array, then TS will preserve in the type of the map, the actual literal types for the keys.

You can then use a mapped type to extract the type of the map key (`keyof` returns the type members, does not hake anything to do  with the map key)

```
const svgAttributeToCssStyle = new Map([
  ["alignment-baseline", "alignmentBaseline"],
  ["baseline-shift", "baselineShift"],
  ["clip", "clip"],
  ["clip-path", "clipPath"],
  // ...
] as const);

type MapKeyType<T extends Map<any, any>> = T extends Map<infer K, any> ? K : never;
export function getPresentationAttribute(attribute: MapKeyType<typeof svgAttributeToCssStyle>) {

}

getPresentationAttribute("clip-path")
getPresentationAttribute("clipPath") // errr
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=66&ssc=45&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBBuBzAglKAnAlgIwK5QFMAVEAYQggGUoBPAGwJgF4YwCB3GAWQEMAHABQBtALAAoGDCEAiHnUyIwAWwJgoAWmw8IBeW2kAaGLPmKVagELbdmfQF0D4yTK069BdRAAWmAGZRDY1cbNkoff2kHJylpYHk+QNj4yMcJGLjMPnU+HigvRIy+AAVc-Ki0mVA6EHQCkGra8udY+pr1W0J0PnrczHA6hoBJNQIunqg+sBToytb0dpGxul7wdV9MOk6IAZrhzu7lifAAMQ2t6YrY3HQIGoLr28bU5oATTHQCYCOpo2k3j6+kwur0wED4yxoiTeYIhwJiLxASlsPDUmms7ihiORlnRtgIcJkqh42AYaOAAGtEOgQLgwC9EkSSQQrBSqTS6QTpOs6HREtzeU0Yvz1CAcsBMLQ+Rs6AB5MUSyGCmTC9C4BhSnkAJTV+KVXLOow1nU5vmqIBe6iqd1+ppA5tIcxNZotop44slNudcrdCpN4A0vh4SLokJt-uOQY2iueQv9nkwAC98WG1JRE7qY8q4xB0+oeC8AFa4aB8-1ppPIQvFgJ63zZjAEKDAfIpqDUD5NsqZrn1+jJ4x11O0dW1uPwHhYFEBVsANQnmCnftR7AICi804H-oA6qvEOvOYgQ3wvCKsKooCswOovDVE-65IlDzRjzKz2pLwAJW8J+8C7tP49T0wc9L3UeBRgmYAH1+ACvFfYD32+GcIMwKC-xmaRMCUHhEA8D46VGWxEESLCcIITVVBeQiwGIvVyVGMAiMSej0EYmjOQYNBRk8eV2N+TjOkoXjaO7Ux1yIy1HX4tcJhoh0Gk5bD0BY9RKMSJSWIAUQ5PUNO4pF6V+PT0C4TB6V0icVOgCcN2kYzqBsxTtHJdTnM5V13VDYwPN9PUQHA9BbXYRJ-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-eeIEAFoEvmvEBhQSgY0fgAenQZndAOCgA)